# Wrapping Ruby With An Anonymous Module

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

There are several Ruby C API functions for running some Ruby code. Most just run the code in an isolated binding like `require` does. But some of them first *wrap the code in an anonymous module* before running it. For example, `rb_load` takes an argument for whether you want this wrapping, `rb_eval_string_wrap` is just `rb_eval_string_protect` but with wrapping.

In C, the wrapping looks like this:

```
/* load in anonymous module as toplevel */
th->top_self = rb_obj_clone(rb_vm_top_self());
th->top_wrapper = rb_module_new();
rb_extend_object(th->top_self, th->top_wrapper);
```

What is the point of doing this? I've tested these functions alongside their unwrapped equivalents and the result is always the same. Is there some use-case I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should've done some more testing. It looks like this is a [bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10466).

The point of wrapping code in an anonymous module is to not pollute the toplevel namespace with constants/methods defined in the code. `rb_load` does this wrapping properly, `rb_eval_string_wrap` does not.